# Unity 5.6 - Can no longer select empty GameObject with Gizmo in editor

Tags: unity, c#

Has anyone else noticed this?
I'm using the latest version of Unity (5.6.0p2) and it appears Gizmos are no longer selectable by default.

Is there any way to restore this behaviour?

Some of my objects are essentially empty (no meshrenderer/Filter) with a MonoBehavior attached, which require a gizmo drawn sphere so it can be selected.

Is there a better/more appropriate way of making non-mesh gameobjects selectable in the editor that I'm not aware of?

I understand I could use Handles to detect a mouse click but this doesn't allow for simple drag selection (marquee tool) if I want to select a load at once.

Comment: If this is a regression, submit a bug using the Unity Editor.

Comment: I had a problem with this recently, and it turned out the layer my object was on had been locked out of selection by default. Open up the [Layers drop-down](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html) and double-check that your object's layer is not locked.

Comment: That was it, I forgot about layers. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the comment thread above, it appears that the problem was that the user had unintentionally left one of their layers locked.

You can use the [Layers drop-down menu in the Unity Editor toolbar](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html) to configure which object layers should be selectable.

Comment: @hedgehog90 remember to mark the question as answered as soon as you can, if you solved your problem